# why doesn't 'url query' seem to work in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, query-string, nsurl

I am trying to start my app from a url, and am using the querystring to get information on the details to start the application. I seem to be having problems with the [NSURL query] method.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation(id)annotation
NSString *queryString = [url query];
[queryString doSomethingWithIt];
```

queryString fails to receive anything from the [url query] method, despite the debugger suggesting that url contains a string that has a query within it.
If I use the following (rather inelegant) workaround it seems to work:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation(id)annotation
NSString *wholeURL = [url absoluteString];
NSString *queryString = [[wholeURL componentsSeparatedByString:@"?"] objectAtIndex:1];
[queryString doSomethingWithIt];
```

This error is not listed in the Documentation. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Do you have an example URL that doesn't work?

Comment: (fmTimer:://x-callback-url/examination?profile=rcoa&exam=primary&sitting=SOE1&candidate=123&cubicle=A&round=3)  Is it in there that the problem lies - I thought I had formatted it correctly!

Comment: Why `fmTimer:://...` and not `fmTimer://...`?

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid - thanks so much - I will check that but I am sure it will be the problem. AHHHHH!!